# Elegant way to prove that the space must be infinite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $F(S,V)$ be the set of all functions from S to a vector space V,
>   assume that $V\ne\{0\}$, and that S contains infinitely many elements, then we must have that $F(S,V)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Is there an easy way to prove this? In order to show this I had to do a lot of work, first reduce the problem to the case where S is countable, and then consider some functions on the countable space etc.. It seems like such a simple fact that there should be a very simple proof?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_0$ be some nonzero element of $V$. Take a sequence of elements of $S$, call it $x_i$. Let $e_i(x)=y_0$ if $x=x_i$ and $0$ otherwise. Prove that the $e_i$ for $i=1\dots,n$ are linearly independent and yet do not span $F(S,V)$.

Comment: You should replace $1$ with a nontrivial element from $V$.

Comment: @Dominik Thanks.

Comment: +1.  I think it might be (very slightly) tidier not to introduce the sequence.  Just define $e_s$ for each $s\in S$; then $\{e_s : s\in S\}$ is linearly independent, so $\dim F(S,V)\ge\operatorname{card} S$.  Introducing the sequence may prompt foundational questions (can we choose a sequence from any infinite set?  does this need the axiom of choice?)  which, though interesting, obscure the matter at hand.